# QR reader Android

Tags: android, qr-code

I am trying to build an application with built in QR reader
but after searching for many tutorials, I still can't get the correct way
here is the error I faced and I have totally no idea with it
any please help me

[image: Error Message]

[image: Here is my code]

[image: Core]

Comment: Have you added the library in your application ?

Comment: do you mean the core.jar? yes I added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include `core.jar` in your Android project. You usually put it in `libs/` so the build tool will package it into your app. It doesn't exist in your .apk otherwise.

Comment: I go Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs
and added the core.jar ald.. but it didnt show in libs folder..
see my print screen above

Comment: That's not going to make the build tools put the classes in your .apk. I use the command line tools and I just put the .jar in libs/